# Using distance in Point2D to compare variable to array

Tags: java, arrays, loops, boolean

My goal is to return true if a Door is near by (a Door is a subclass of Game Object and the allObjectsInWorld is an ArrayList which contains all the game objects in the world including this door)
I return false when i  am close to the door.
get is door returns true if the object is a door

GameObject.position is  a Point2D point

```
public boolean isDoorNear(GameObject user) {
    boolean tempBoo = false;
    for(int i = 0; i < allObjectsInWorld.size();i++) {
        GameObject a = (GameObject) allObjectsInWorld.get(i);  //checks to see if something is there
        if( user.position.distance(a.position) <= 2.0 && a.isDoor) {
            tempBoo = true;
        }
        else {
            tempBoo = false;
        }
    }
    return tempBoo; 
}
```

Comment: What are the classes? GameObject? Door?

Answer (score 1):

The line `tempBoo = false` is bad: it changes the return value to `true` even if some door was detected before. Simply rely on the initialization to provide the default return of `false` unless there was any door nearby.

But you can avoid all that `tempBoo` stuff completely by returning early:

```
public boolean isDoorNear(GameObject user) {
    for(int i = 0; i < allObjectsInWorld.size();i++) {
        GameObject a = (GameObject) allObjectsInWorld.get(i);
        if( user.position.distance(a.position) <= 2.0 && a.isDoor)
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: thanks..that is how I had it at first... must have had an xtra brace or something there